# inserting data into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have just installed xampp but I'm having problem inserting data into MySQL table. 
The data I inserted does not appear in phpmyadmin. I am not sure what is the problem.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated, here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit"name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

<?php 
$host ="localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$database = "***";
$table ="persons";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","***","***");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
 mysql_select_db("bucksbug_mesovot", $con);

 $sql="INSERT INTO persons (firstname, lastname, age)
 VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
   echo "Data inserted";

   mysql_close($con);

  ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? - Also remember to check if form is posted before trying to add with something like: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {}

Comment: Why are you still using `mysql_*` when it has been deprecated?

Comment: STOP working on this code until you've learned about and learned how to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). otherwise your server is going to go up in flames. And you'll probably want to change your database password, since you've now plastered it all over the interwebitubes for everyone to see.

Comment: Wow. Please tell me that you really didn't just post your password

Comment: What does the script return if you echo $sql one the line after it is defined?

Comment: Comment out this line `$con = mysql_connect("localhost","bucksbug_****","=c*****Jm");` it contains your password.

Answer (score 2):

Although you should really switch to PDO / mysqli and prepared statements with bound parameters to avoid sql injection and breaking sql statements if your variables contain quotation marks, you will probably run into problems with PDO / mysqli as well: Your password (change it!) contains a `$`.

See the following example on [codepad](http://codepad.org/YjTqFouW):

```
<?php

function test($var)
{
  echo $var;
}

$test_var = "test$string";

test($test_var);
```

Output:

```
test
```

You will not be able to connect successfully to the database as your password will never be correct.

Change:

```
"=c(p$zTTH2Jm"
```

to:

```
'=c(p$zTTH2Jm'
```